# Why folder size is different from result of PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am running PowerShell code to check a folder size. I just noticed that the result is different from what I see in Windows GUI of folder properties.

part of PowerShell code:

```powershell
@{label="Size" ; expression={(Get-childitem "c:\windows" -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum}}
```

Results are not the same....?

[image]

BTW, how to display the size in GB based on the code above?

Hint please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get different results is hidden files and folders. To account for these use *-Force* switch on `Get-childitem`:

```powershell
@{label="Size" ; expression={(Get-childitem -force "c:\windows" -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum}}
```

To get your total into GBs just divide the result by `1Gb`, ie:

```powershell
@{label="Size" ; expression={(Get-childitem -force "c:\windows" -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum/1Gb}}
```

Or to round it up to one decimal point:

```powershell
 @{label="Size" ; expression={[math]::round(((Get-childitem -force "c:\windows" -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum/1Gb),1)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. `-force` solved the question. btw, how can I combine `"{0:N2}" -f` into that `expression=`, cuz now the result have 13 numbers after dot like this: `21.0008407654241`, I used to use `"{0:N2}" -f ($folder.sum / 1024MB) + " GB"` to output the size seperatly..

Comment: You can use `[math]::round` function from my third example, just change the second parameter to 2, ie: `...sum/1Gb),2)..`

Comment: wow,`[math]::round`...good to know it. it is perfect now. Thank you very much!